# Keep an iOS app running in foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, background, foreground

I would like to know if there's a way to keep an app running in foreground, during a specific interval time.

I have a thread running exactly during 3 minutes and I need that the user cannot leave the app. If such a thing is not possible I'm going to ask another question.

I could let that the user set the app in background mode because I use the `applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method to save the data I need but if the user clicks the power button, how could I save the data?

The `applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` would be called? Is there any solution?

Comment: First, You cannot force your app to be on the foreground.

Comment: you can save the data in User Defaults until the data is not saved and after that clear the user defaults

Comment: It's more than saving data in User Defaults, I'm saving data in plist, I'm also using Coredata, the thing is that i need a point to save all this information if the user tries to turn off the device.

Comment: So u need to keep u r application live even u forcely put u r application in background ? In my application i have handle this kind of situation.

Comment: Actually i don't mind if the app is not alive once it's in background because like I've said before I use the applicationDidEnterBackground method to save all information i need, however if I'm using the app and I decide to turn off the iPhone in that moment, how could i save the information?

Comment: Me - "Well that was fun, but I think I'm done playing this game"

The Game - "Too bad, you'll keep playing. This isn't optional!"

Comment: @Ganapathy, I have same issue to keep app live in background, can you please suggest how can I keep app live in background?

Comment: By default apple does not allow application to run in background not more than 10 mins. if you want to continue the task more than 10 mins you need to bring your app to foreground.

Comment: My answer reflect the peace of code to bring up the app after 10mins once it enters background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, which lets your app request additional processing time to complete tasks when your app is backgrounded.

That said, what you're looking to do isn't advisable. You should make sure your app can recover from your three minute task in case of unexpected termination or failure. For example, your app could crash unexpectedly or terminate due to low memory - in these cases, you won't get any callbacks to `applicationWillTerminate` or `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

So my recommendation would be to look at using iOS's background task support to have your save continue in the background if the user leaves the app, but also ensure that in the event your app be terminated by the system without warning your task is recoverable / can safely be rewound.

Comment: I had understood that in case of unexpectedly error, i could handle it using didReceiveMemoryWarning but as i'm reading, the app could crash without receiving a warning?

Comment: `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is only called for memory warnings, not other types of crash: it's also possible that you may not have enough time in response to a memory warning to resolve things, especially if something is trying to make a huge allocation. Basically, your app should be able to handle termination without warning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to handle your process alive. use this code.

Here I called this method from applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application to store the data in SQlite even the application enter background or UIApplicationStateInactive (press power button). Saving process will continue for 10 mins as per the IOS standard if application.backgroundTimeRemaining comes to 0 I will post one local notification to bring up my application to foreground to keep my process alive. use this code and customize your process.

```
-(void)handleBackgroundSavingingProcess:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        NSLog(@"background task remaining time before background %f",application.backgroundTimeRemaining);

        if ((([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground) || ([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive)) && [application respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)])
  {


     self.bgTaskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
     // Synchronize the cleanup call on the main thread in case
     // the task actually finishes at around the same time.
                NSLog(@"background task remaining time in expiration handler %f",application.backgroundTimeRemaining);

                dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue;
                if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 5.0)
                    concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0UL);
                else
                    concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0UL);

                if (concurrentQueue == nil)
                    return;

                dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

                    if (self.bgTaskId != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
                        NSLog(@"background task remaining time in dispatch queue %f",application.backgroundTimeRemaining);
                        NSLog(@" Downloading status %d",self.isDownloadingInComplete);
                        if(self.isDownloadingInComplete)
                        {
                            [application presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
                            NSLog(@"Local notification fired.");
                        }
                        [DataManager managedObjectContext] save:nil];
                        [application endBackgroundTask:self.bgTaskId];
                        self.bgTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                        NSLog(@"Initialization invalid.");
                    }
                });
            }];
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Ganapathy, Will this method keep live my app in background...?

Comment: Your app will be in background upto 10 mins by default . what this method will do is after 10 mins it will show one alert that your task is running in background for 10 mins (customize the content). After receiving the alert you need to bring back the app to foreground.